# Linq join time error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create a list using a join on a table. I've commented out the code that doesn't work, but is the code I need. When I run this I get a cast date time error. I'm wondering if I should be trying this join to get the data or run a subquery of this result, which I can't figure out how to do.

If BeingSeen is null then I want the BeingSeen property in the new object to be null.

Any suggestions on the right way to fill this 'BeingSeen' property?

```
                object PatientsNotSeen;
                using (var db = new SyDbConn())
                {
                    PatientsNotSeen = (from events in db.Events
                        where
                            events.ClinicId == clinicId && events.StatusId != 6 &&
                            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(events.stime) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)
                        //join beingSeen in db.BeingSeenStatus on events.PatientId equals beingSeen.PatientId into caa
                        //from beingSeen in caa.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            PatientID = events.PatientId,
                            events.PatientName,
                            AppointmentTime = events.stime,
                            // BeingSeen = beingSeen.TimeStarted
                        }).ToList();
                }
```

When uncomment the comments and run this is the error:

```
Additional information: The cast to value type 
'System.DateTime' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic 
parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

Comment: Try this: `BeingSeen = beingSeen.TimeStarted ?? DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: @RahulSingh BeingSeen = (DateTime?) beingSeen.TimeStarted ?? DateTime.MinValue worked. I'll accept it as an answer if you post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Null Coalesce` operator:-

```
BeingSeen = beingSeen.TimeStarted ?? DateTime.MinValue
```

If TimeStarted property is not `Nullable` then simply type-cast it:-

```
BeingSeen = (DateTime?)beingSeen.TimeStarted ?? DateTime.MinValue
```